# If I ask a question on a 3d engine, which site should I ask it on?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

If I have a question about the coding capabilities of, say, the Unity game engine, should I ask it on Stack Overflow, Game development, or Arqade?

Comment: Arqade is about *playing* games, not coding anything. Did you check the FAQ of each site yet?

Comment: It might help somewhat if you include an example of what you would like to ask. Unity3D questions are absolutely welcome on Stack Overflow, but "coding capabilities" would make me hesitant to recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Gamedev and Stack Overflow ought to be fine. I would say that gamedev is better in this case since it is a more qualitative question.

Comment: Why? If I put it on arqade, wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: @Randumbness Arqade is about gaming, not coding games.

Comment: So why is there a Unity 3D tag on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Randumbness Where did I say that it is inappropriate on Stack Overflow? I just said that Game Dev would be better than Stack Overflow, and Arqade would be inappropriate.

Comment: Also, the existence of a tag does not automatically make all questions on that tag on topic.

Answer (score 4):

You should always check the site FAQ. [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) includes:

> - game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc)

in the on-topic list, so I'd ask there.

The [Arqade FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *specifically prohibits* game development questions. In their **off-topic** list they have:

> - Game and Mod Development (try the Game Development Stack Exchange instead)

which helpfully points you to Game Development.

Your question would probably on-topic on Stack Overflow as well, but if you are looking for specialist help, Game Dev would give you more exposure to experts.